# Linking problem in Xcode when using a dependent subproject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build-process

I am using Xcode to write an iPhone project and I use an external library. I added the Xcode project file to the parent target and adjusted the header search path and set it as a direct dependency in the parent's build target.

Now the strange thing happens: I can open the library and compile it without problems. The library links to some frameworks e.g. `AVFoundation.framework`.

I clean the target and start building the parent project. In my build results I see that it builds the library, but then the linking fails with these error messages:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium", referenced from:
      _AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium$non_lazy_ptr in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
     (maybe you meant: _AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController presentResultForString:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController viewWillAppear:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*)in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*)in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*)in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVCaptureSession in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVCaptureDevice in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
      _kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey$non_lazy_ptr in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
     (maybe you meant: _kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoDataOutput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVCaptureVideoDataOutput in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController dealloc] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVCaptureDeviceInput in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
      _AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill$non_lazy_ptr in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
     (maybe you meant: _AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
      -[ZXingWidgetController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      zxing::qrcode::DecodedBitStreamParser::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, char const*)in libZXingWidget.a(DecodedBitStreamParser-64E27B33E79CBC52.o)
  "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      _AVMediaTypeVideo$non_lazy_ptr in libZXingWidget.a(ZXingWidgetController.o)
     (maybe you meant: _AVMediaTypeVideo$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can include the needed frameworks in the parent project, but I thought that by including the frameworks in the library project the linking would be OK.

**My question is:** Do I have to include all the frameworks that my dependent subprojects use in the parent project to ensure proper linking, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the subproject compiles into a static lib, yes.

Comment: I am compiling into a static lib, because it is meant for iOS. That is really inconvenient. Why is linking in the subproject not enough?

Comment: Static libs don't actually link to anything themselves. Only executables and dynamic libs go through the linking process. I'm not entirely sure on how Xcode handles framework references, but it's possible you need to reference even standard frameworks to see their header files. I'm sure someone else could give a definitive answer on that.

Answer (score 9):

make sure include "CoreMedia.framework","AudioToolbox.framework","CoreGraphics.framework","CoreVideo.framework","AVFoundation.framework","libiconv.dylib" 
frameworks in project in Build Phases